# neo4j-graphql-schema: Cypher query to Graphql Schema and query

Tags: neo4j, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java, github-graphql

I tested the following query in a Neo4j browser and it worked.  Now I am trying to  define a schema and query for a React app using the neo4j-graphql-js plugin/driver (import { neo4jgraphql } from "neo4j-graphql-js";). My issue is I do not know how to define a schema that will take 2 parameters, example: action(startTime: {epoch}, endTime: {epoch}).  The action node in the DB has the following properties: action, timelist and timestamp.

```
MATCH (sec:Second)<-[:AT_TIME]-(act:action)-[:TARGET]->(obj:object)
WHERE act.timestamp >= 1499350389000 AND act.timestamp <= 1499350389000 
RETURN sec, act, obj
```

Comment: I'm I thinking about this problem the wrong way?  I have spent all day looking for an example that includes passing date/time as parameters in a schema and still have not found any.  All I've seen are types with different parameters, ex(ID and name) but none with (startTime, endTime).  The problem I am running into is that I can only declare timestamp (a property of an object) once.  So I can't do (timestamp, timestamp).  Also, you cannot introduce new parameters in your schema.  The only ones you can use are the ones in found in the Neo4j DB. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Also found out I cannot define a type that is not an object in my DB. Like: Type interval.  Because interval is not an object in my DB.

Comment: So my DB does not know what is startTime/endTime it only knows timestamp which is a property of the action object, which is what I am after.  So I need someway to define startTime/endTime that Neo4j will understand...

Comment: This is what I am trying to the do.  Found in 'Parameterizing Fields with Arguments' section. Ref: https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/2-more-graphql-concepts/